# Que hace la función assert?

Tags: python, python-3.x

He visto en algunos programas y en la web que utilizan la función ***assert*** ,por ejemplo :

```
Assert True
```

No hace nada, mientras que:

```
Assert False
```

Manda un error de AssertationError...

Aun no me queda claro para que sirve esta función.

Alguna idea ?

Gracias!

Comment: Hay una respuesta muy buena (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5142453/7291849) en el sitio de StackOverflow en ingles. Creo q esto puede responder tu pregunta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lo que hace ya está explicado en otras respuestas. Me voy a extender un poco más en para qué se usa. Tiene dos usos principales.

### Detectar errores de programación

El primero es incluir en tu programa una especie de "red de seguridad" ante posibles errores del programador. Imagina que llamas a una función de la que sabes que jamás retorna un valor negativo, y usas su respuesta como parte de otra operación:

```
a = otra_funcion()
return 1 + a
```

Insisto, la `otra_funcion()` jamás retornará un negativo. Si lo hiciera estaría mal. Pero no te fías del todo, pues quizás esa función no ha sido escrita por ti y quizás en una actualización posterior de la librería que la incluye aparece un bug y retorna un negativo. `assert` te permite expresar una condición que ha de ser cierta siempre, ya que de no serlo se interrumpirá el programa. Podríamos añadir `assert` así:

```
a = otra_funcion()
assert a >= 0        # Asegurarse de que es positivo
return a + 1
```

Mientras efectivamente `a` sea positivo, es como si no hubiéramos añadido el `assert`, pues no hace nada. Pero si alguna vez fuese negativo, estamos tranquilos pues el `assert` interrumpirá el programa y volcará una traza señalando el punto del programa en que el `assert` falló.

Podemos incluir un mensaje que formaría parte de la excepción que se genera cuando la expresión sea falsa. Así:

```
a = otra_funcion()
assert a >= 0, "otra_funcion() ha retornado un negativo!"
return a + 1
```

Este mensaje formaría parte del error si llega a producirse la excepción, y nos ayudará a localizar el problema.

Un detalle importante es que el `assert` debe usarse para cazar condiciones que *no deberían ocurrir jamás*, y si ocurren deben considerarse un error de programación. Si, en cambio, es posible que la función retorne negativos pero en mi aplicacion concreta no me sirve y quiero considerarlo un error, lo normal sería usar un `if` para verificarlo y, si es necesario, generar una excepción más apropiada. Por ejemplo:

```
a = otra_funcion()
if a<0:
    raise ValueError("El resultado negativo no es válido aquí")
return 1 + a
```

### Testing

Cuando estás escribiendo *tests unitarios* (que consisten en llamar a una función cuyo resultado ya sabes de antemano cuál ha de ser, pero estás comprobando que efectivamente retorna lo que esperabas), el `assert` te sirve para verificar que el valor es el esperado.

Por ejemplo, supón que has escrito una función llamada `raiz_cuadrada()` y quieres comprobar si funciona bien. Puedes escribir algunos test de este estilo:

```
resultado = raiz_cuadrada(25)
assert resultado == 5.0

resultado = raiz_cuadrada(0)
assert resultado == 0.0
```

Típicamente habría más test, pero para pillar la idea es suficiente.

Cuando ejecutas estos test desde un entorno de automatización de pruebas, ese entorno va capturando los `AssertionError` que se produzcan, de modo que al final puede darte un informe de cuántos test han fallado (y cuáles), para que revises la función que no se comportaba como esperabas.

El testing es muy importante durante el desarrollo, pues si modificas la función `raiz_cuadrada()` para corregir un bug que tenía, quieres estar seguro de que no has introducido otro bug al hacerlo. El tener una buena batería de tests y que sigan pasando todos después de haber modificado el código es fundamental.

Answer (score 4):

El assert es una instruccion de Python que te permite definir condiciones que deban cumplirse siempre.  En caso que la expresion booleana sea True assert no hace nada y en caso de False dispara una excepcion.

```
  >>> assert 5 == 5
  >>> assert 6 < 2
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  AssertionError
  >>>
```

Se pueden usar como pre y post condiciones en métodos, funciones, bloques de código pero sobre todo para especificar invariantes. Es mas corto que escribir una sentencia if, mucho mas claro para el que lo lee y como bonus la sentencia no se ejecuta en caso que el intérprete se invoque con -O.

Por eso cuando hacer:

```
Assert False
```

Salta una excepción ***AssertionError*** que podrías capturar en un ***try/except***

Puedes encontrarlo todo en la documentación oficial: [Doc Oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement)